# Difference between two method calls

Tags: ios, swift, difference, completionhandler

Given the following definition:

```
func retrieveData(for id: Int, completion: @escaping (Record) -> ())
```

What is the difference between the following two calls to *retrieveData*?

first call:

```
let id: Int = 1 
retrieveData(id: id) {
    self.update(with: $0)
}
```

second call:

```
let id: Int = 1 
retrieveData(id: id, completion: {
    self.update(with: $0)
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the method,

```
func retrieveData(for id: Int, completion: @escaping (Record) -> ())
```

`completion` is a **Trailing Closure**. It is *method's final argument*. So, in *Swift* we can omit writing the *argument label* in the list while calling the method, i.e.

```
retrieveData(for: id) {
    //your code..
}
```

You can also call it like,

```
retrieveData(for: id, completion: {
    //your code..
})
```

So, it can be called in both ways. Your choice. Although the first one is more cleaner and recommended. Read more about it [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer -

In Swift, functions are first class objects, that means that they can be passed as parameters.

In your examples, when there is a function that takes another function as an argument, you can either write the argument inline, using trailing closure syntax:

```swift
let id: Int = 1 
retrieveData(id: id) {
    self.update(with: $0)
}
```

But look at the function `update(with:)` it is a function that takes a `Record` and returns Void.

Another way to write this, rather than calling the function in the closure, is to just pass the function:

```swift
let id: Int = 1 
retrieveData(id: id, completion: update)
```

Notice that you don't pass it a parameter, or oven brackets. When you pass a function this way, you are passing the function itself, not the result of evaluating the function.

I think this is even cleaner at the call site.